# Problems with JDK on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

When I go to install JDK on my virtual machine, I get the following:

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
* default-jdk
* ecj
* gcj-4.8-jdk
* openjdk-7-jdk
* gcj-4.6-jdk
* openjdk-6-jdk
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

And then when I do the apt-get, I get this:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/username# apt-get install ecj
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ecj
```

Any suggestions on how to fix my problem?

Comment: Do you want to install Oracle JDK ?

Answer (score 2):

You can install oracle JDK 8 on ubuntu like this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

If you want Java7, then change java8 to java7 in last command E.g.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

If you are behind a proxy then you will need to export your proxy env

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

and then notify sudo to use them

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

or append `Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"` at the end of `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: It gives me the error that it can't add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/java'

Comment: @Lipee Are you behind some proxy?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: What would my host be on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Lipee It should be name of your proxyserver

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install java 8 correctly,

First update the apt-get repos

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Add the java 8 repo to apt-get

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Again update the apt-get repo

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install java 8

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```